# CSS Grid wrapping with grid-area coordinates

Tags: css, css-grid

I am trying to display a dashboard with cards, which should have a predetermined coordinates and dimensions (x, y, width, height) when in full screen. Because of that, I set `grid-area: x1, y1, x2, y2` on the cards.

The issue is that I can't get it to wrap on smaller screens.

Coordinates and dimensions for the grid area come from a dashboard editor in which users lay out cards on a predefined grid anywhere they want, and they can resize cards to any size they want.

Is there a way to make this wrap, or is there another way?

```css
.container {
  height: max-content;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(80px, 1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: 80px;
  gap: 16px;
  min-width: 320px;
  display: grid;
  width: 100%;
}

.container > * {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="card1" style="grid-area: 1 / 1 / 5 / 9;"></div>
  <div class="card2" style="grid-area: 5 / 1 / 7 / 5;"></div>
  <div class="card3" style="grid-area: 5 / 5 / 7 / 9;"></div>
  <div class="card4" style="grid-area: 7 / 1 / 9 / 5;"></div>
  <div class="card5" style="grid-area: 7 / 5 / 9 / 9;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you set position for each cards, it will stick to it

Comment: @G-Cyrillus Is there a workaround to still get the desired behavior in full screen at least? E.g. tell every card please span so many cells if possible. Or perhaps, setting the width and height on each card?

Comment: would this be what you actually look for ? https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/poeYvdX

Comment: Almost! So far so good, but as soon as I add `grid-column: auto / span 4` to all the cards (with the first one having span 8) the wrapping no longer works.

Comment: Here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/z0uwf6rL/

Comment: span 8 & span 4 makes a difference of 50% :(

Answer (score 1):

you may set spanning to your grid items if you wish without setting a grid cell position.

calc() can also help to set a break point sparing a mediaquerie .

here is an example *to set manually if your dashboard cannot be tuned otherwise* :

```css
.container {
  height: max-content;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax( calc(25vw + 160px) , 1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: 80px;
  gap: 16px;
  min-width: 320px;
  display: grid;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container > * {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="card1" style="grid-column:1 / -1 ;
                            grid-row:auto / span 4">1</div>
  <div class="card2" style="grid-row:auto / span 2">2</div>
  <div class="card3" style="grid-row:auto / span 2">3</div>
  <div class="card4" style="grid-row:auto / span 2">4</div>
  <div class="card5" style="grid-row:auto / span 2">5</div>
</div>
```